# deploy bolts/spout to a specific supervisor

Tags: apache-storm

We are running a storm application using a single type on instance in AWS and a single topology to run our system.

This is causing some resource limitation issues.
The way we want to address this is by splitting our IO intense bolts into a cluster of a few dozens t1.small machines (for example) and all our CPU intense bolts to two large machines with lots of cpu & memory.

Basically what i am asking is, is there a way to start all this supervisors and then deploy one topology that include cpu intense bolts on the big machines and to the small machines the deploy IO bolts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom scheduler using interface `IScheduler`.

See

- http://www.exogeni.net/2015/04/enabling-site-aware-scheduling-for-apache-storm-in-exogeni/
- https://dcvan24.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/metadata-aware-custom-scheduler-in-storm/
- https://github.com/xumingming/storm-lib/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/DemoScheduler.java

Comment: Wonderful, i was hoping for something like that!, thanks!

Comment: This seems to have changed in storm 1.0.x any idea how to implement this at that version?

Comment: In Storm `1.0` there was a major refactoring with regard to package names. `IScheduler` is now `org.apache.storm.scheduler.IScheduler.java`. The code itself did not change, and it should work as before. See also http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/index.html

Comment: something with:

supervisor.scheduler.meta:
    group-id: 1

cause problems, the supervisor is up, but the worker is not, any ideas?

thanks